# Angular, queuing ng-init

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-init

Is it possible queuing ng-init?
Generally, in first init I want to add JSON file to prototype vars (array) and in another init depending on the params I want to skip getJsonData() or add other JSON file to prototype.

```
function init(param) {
        console.log("startInit");

        // big JSON file
        var promise =  getJSON(param);  
        return promise.then( function() {
            //some func
            console.log("finish");
            return true;
        });
    };

    function getJSON(param) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        console.log("startInitDataInner");
            someService.getJsonData(param).then(function(data) {
                // some code
                console.log("endInitDataInner");
                deferred.resolve();

            }, function(error) {
                deferred.reject();
            });

        return deferred.promise; 

    };
```

in view ng-init

```
ng-init="init(param)"
ng-init="init(param)"
// ...
```

and log:

```
startInit
startInitDataInner
startInit
startInitDataInner
endInitDataInner
finish
endInitDataInner
finish
//..
```

Edit:
Generally, I want to create something like plugin in jQuery. I have this code:

```
<div ng-controller="parentController as parent">
   <div ng-controller="childController as child" ng-init="child.init(parent.data)"></div>
</div>

<div ng-controller="parentController as parent">
   <div ng-controller="childController as child" ng-init="child.init(parent.data2)"></div>
</div>
```

and configurable part by user:

```
 angular.module('myApp').controller('parentController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
 this.data = {
    config: {
       lang: "en",
       title: "title"
       }
 };
 this.data2 = {
    config: {
       lang: "pl",
       title: "title2"
    }
 };         
 }]);
```

ng-init update api:

```
angular.extend(this, parent.data);
```

Do you have any ideas how I should do it differently?

Comment: Don't use `ng-init` for this

Comment: This isn't an [appropriate use for `ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit).  If you aren't aliasing a property of `ng-repeat` or trying to initialize a parameter from a server side script, use a controller to initialize your variables.

Comment: `ng-init` is a wrong choice to make asynchronous call and have dependent code on it.. look at the Docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Comment: I am assuming that the Answer you posted was actually meant to be more information on the question.  I still believe that this isn't the correct usage for `ng-init`.  If you are attempting to make "configurable plugins", then you should consider creating a directive rather than a nested child controller.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are working with angular, you use controllers. What is controller itslfmin general meaning? Right, its a constructor function. The main word here is **function**. What does function in general? Run the code inside.

So, just place your initial logic at the beggining of controller code (but without wrapping it as a separate function) and it will run just in time your controller will be resolved by angular resolver.

```
var controller = function () {
    // vars, costs, etc.
    console.log("startInit");

    // big JSON file
    var promise =  getJSON(param);  
    return promise.then( function() {
        //some func
        console.log("finish");
        return true;
    });

};
```